# Where did this zram swap come from?

Tags: 12.04, zram

I have a zram swap (and a normal one) and I got no idea where it came from:

```
$ sudo blkid | grep zram
/dev/zram0: UUID="..." TYPE="swap"

$ lsmod | grep zram
zram                   18642  1

$ cat $ cat /etc/fstab
# <file system>         <mount point>   <type>   <options>                             <dump>  <pass>
proc                    /proc           proc     nodev,noexec,nosuid                   0       0
tmpfs                   /tmp            tmpfs    defaults,noatime,mode=1777            0       0
UUID=...                /               ext4     discard,noatime,errors=remount-ro     0       1
/dev/disk/by-uuid/...   /mnt/data       ext4     defaults,user,exec,errors=remount-ro  0       2
/dev/disk/by-uuid/...   /mnt/media      ext4     defaults,user,errors=remount-ro       0       2
UUID=...                none            swap     sw                                    0       0
```

1. Where did come from?
2. How can I get rid of it, besides blacklisting `zram`?

This is happening only on one of my systems, both running Ubuntu 12.04 Alpha 2+.

Comment: Did some nasty package install `zram-config` in your system?

Comment: Nope, not installed.

Comment: `zram` is in fact [a useful tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZRam), so I recommend that you keep it. It is most effective on systems with low RAM; e.g. Lubuntu uses it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forgot to check the files in `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` and indeed, I found some `compcache` related files. I then checked, which package installed those files, e.g.

```
sudo dpkg -S /usr/share/initramfs-tools/conf.d/compcache
```

points to the package `casper`. Now, I got no idea how this ended up on my system, but purging it and recreating the initrd, gets rid of the zram swap.

Answer (score 0):

In 12.04 final this is part of initramfs-tools:

```
$ lsb_release -rd
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:    12.04
$ dpkg -S /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/compcache
initramfs-tools: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/compcache
$
```

Comment: Note though that the initramfs-tools support does nothing unless enabled in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf.