# How to disable zram at boot

Tags: boot, zram

How to disable zram at boot?

What I found was mostly to

```
swapoff -a
rmmod zram
```

but after reboot it came back

I found such question being asked at different places, e.g.,

- https://forum.garudalinux.org/t/disable-zram/1580/5
- https://github.com/VR-25/zram-swap-manager/issues/2
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-to-disable-zram-permanently-at-boot.2946997/
- https://www.reddit.com/r/LineageOS/comments/5v1xwl/how_to_disable_zram/

But none seems to be able to get answered properly.

Comment: Reading the answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287243/how-do-i-replace-zram-swap-with-a-swap-file I think you have to run `sudo systemctl disable nvzramconfig` to disable ZRAM.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance. So I tried it and got _"Failed to disable unit: Unit file nvzramconfig.service does not exist."_, but `sudo systemctl disable zram-config` works! Thanks!!

Comment: Please provide information on the version of your operating system, and how you configured it to use a zram swap space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Arch Linux-based systems, it is possible that zram is configured via [zram-generator](https://archlinux.org/packages/?name=zram-generator) package. The generator is invoked by systemd early at boot. You can check unit status of your configuration service via systemd-zram-setup@zramN.service. N is the zram device id.
To disable generator, set `systemd.zram[=0|1]` kernel parameter.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Then add `systemd.zram=0` argument to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` as follows.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="systemd.zram=0"
```

Then generate grub config file

```
sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```